# comparator for Map.Entry<K,V>

Tags: java, dictionary, comparator

I have a Map with an enumeration type as the key and Double as the value. I want to sort this based on the Double values. So I got the entry set and want to use `Collections.sort()` with a comparator. I have the following code for the comparator

```
class ScoreComparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> implements Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }   
}
```

I am getting the following error messages

1. `Syntax error on token ".", extends expected    (line 1)`.
2. `The type parameter Map is hiding the type Map<K,V> (line 1)`.
3. Because of the above two errors, K and V cannot be resolved to a type (lines 3,4).

I am unable to resolve this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu, No that doesn't work. I get a "The type ScoreComparator must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>.compare(Map.Entry<K,V>, Map.Entry<K,V>)" error. I implement the method as shown in the code above.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer bellow to fix that and still keep the comparator as generic as you intended it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
// Declare K and V as generic type parameters to ScoreComparator
class ScoreComparator<K, V extends Comparable<V>> 

// Let your class implement Comparator<T>, binding Map.Entry<K, V> to T
implements Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>> {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {

        // Call compareTo() on V, which is known to be a Comparable<V>
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }   
}
```

`ScoreComparator` takes two generic type arguments `K` and `V`. `Map.Entry<K, V>` is not a valid generic type definition, but you may well use it to bind to `Comparator<T>`'s `T` type.

Note that `V` must extend `Comparable<V>`, in order to be able to call `compareTo()` on `o1.getValue()`.

You can now use the above `ScoreComparator` as such:

```
new ScoreComparator<String, String>();
new ScoreComparator<Long, Integer>();
// etc...
```

Note, from your current implementation, you probably don't even need the `K` parameter. An alternative:

```
class ScoreComparator<V extends Comparable<V>> 
implements Comparator<Map.Entry<?, V>> {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<?, V> o1, Map.Entry<?, V> o2) {

        // Call compareTo() on V, which is known to be a Comparable<V>
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Raghava: See the updated answer for an alternative that can do without declaring `K`, which isn't needed in the current implementation...

Comment: Thank you. That certainly is concise and better.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to define your own comparator class. You can use `Comparator.comparing` method to create a comparator as demonstrated bellow:

```
import java.util.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Double> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("a", 5.);
        myMap.put("b", 3.);
        myMap.put("c", 11.);

        // Or the following for Java 9 or higher
        // Map<String, Double> myMap = Map.of("a", 5., "b", 3., "c", 11.);

        List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(myMap.entrySet());
        
        System.out.println("Sorted by values:");
        Collections.sort(entryList, Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
        entryList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        
        System.out.println("\nSorted by keys:");
        Collections.sort(entryList, Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey));
        entryList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
Sorted by values:
b=3.0
a=5.0
c=11.0

Sorted by keys:
a=5.0
b=3.0
c=11.0
```